# import React from 'react'

Tags: reactjs, import

When we write code in index.js file in src folder of an React app first of all we write this line:

```js
import React from 'react';
```

I know  react is a package
But I want to know what is React basically
an object, a method or something else.

Comment: Here is a good [explanation](https://djoech.medium.com/why-do-you-need-to-import-react-in-functional-components-7385e4329ffb). Basically `React` is a js object representing the entry point of the library. When writing jsx code like `<p>text</p>`, the transpiler convert it to react element using [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement). That's the reason why you need to import this object in your source file.

Comment: you are refering to below js file  
      https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react/src/React.js

Comment: [This](http://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react/src/React.js) file imports some functionalities for multiple other js files and exports the functionalities by combining them

Answer (score 2):

In order to find out what React is, you just need to write:

```
console.log(react);
```

Then you will see that it is an object with many properties and methods.

String:

```
import React from "react";
```

We are writing in order to import this object into a file where we will use some of its method. If you don't use anything from React in the file, then you don't need to import it.
For example, in react 18, it is no longer necessary to import the react object into a file index.js

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

In any case, at this stage of your study of react, it may not be entirely clear to you what is used in it and for what, but in the future you will become more aware of all the possibilities of react. There is a time for everything

Answer (score 0):

The `React` variable that you import is an `object`, and it contains most of the methods that are used by React when generating a web-page.

The reason this import has been historically required is because the JSX that you write (e.g. `return <p>text</p>`) gets converted into a function call, calling the `React.createElement` function.

---

Note that in newer versions of React you no longer need to import react when using JSX. See https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html for more information.

---

Credit to [Olivier Boissé](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5521607/olivier-boiss%c3%a9) for an answer in  the comments.